# Convert numerical strings in a list to numerical (Integer/float) type

Tags: python

I have a list of mixed types of data:

```
list = ['Diff', '', '', 0, '+16.67%', '+2.81%', 0, '+13.33%']
```

I only want to convert the numerical strings in this list to Integers/float, so my list will be:

```
newlist = ['Diff', '', '', 0, +16.67%, +2.81%, 0, +13.33%]
```

I know this `res = [eval(i) for i in list]` can convert all the strings to integers if everything in my list is numerical strings, but how do I do to only convert the numerical strings in a mixed-type list?

Comment: see https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isnumeric

Comment: 123% is not a valid type, what do you want to convert it to? a float? I'd use a regex to detect those and strip the %

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When doing type conversions in python, you attempt a conversion first and provide a reasonable fallback for the case it fails ("ask forgiveness, not permission"). There are just too many things that can go wrong with a conversion, and it's hard to check them all in advance.

```
def maybe_int(x):
    try:
        return int(x)
    except (TypeError, ValueError):
        return x


lst = ['1', 'yes', 'diff', '43', '2', '4']
print([maybe_int(x) for x in lst])
```

To handle values like `12.34%` you can do something like:

```
def convert(x):
    x = str(x)

    if x.endswith('%'):
        try:
            return float(x[:-1])
        except ValueError:
            return x

    try:
        return float(x)
    except ValueError:
        return x

result = [convert(x) for x in your_list]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it works for the list! I just realize my real list also contains numerical values like  +16.67%.(I updated it in my question) How should I deal with this type?

Comment: `+16.67%` (without quotes) is not a valid python value. What should be these strings converted to?

Comment: I want to know if a number is positive or negative. I want to convert it to +16.67 or +1 if possible

Answer (score -1):

This is one way of doing that by checking if the str [isnumeric](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isnumeric) and type cast to **int** if it is a numeric value.

```
list = ['1', 'yes', 'diff', '43', '2', '4']

print(list)

for i, n in enumerate(list):
  if n.isnumeric():
    list[i] = int(n)

print(list)
```

Comment: you might want to test your answer with something like `⅐`.

Answer (score -1):

I think you can use try-except:

```
for i in range(len(array)):
    try:
        array[i] = int(array[i])
    except:
        print("Can not cast this element to int") # you can write nothing here
```

More info about try-except [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_try_except.asp)

Comment: This is not correct, please test it again!

Comment: Oh, I missed range() accidentally. Edited.

Comment: But, yeah, I forgot about isnumeric, which is the best choose here